# Why does the Cobra Commander ignore Destro?

Tags: plot-explanation, gi-joe-retaliation

In the second movie of the G.I. Joe movie series, **G.I. Joe - Retaliation (2013)**, *Firefly* and *Storm Shadow* launch an assault on the prison that *Cobra Commander* and *Destro* were being held and free *Cobra Commander*. However, upon being freed, *Cobra Commander* decides not to free *Destro* alongside him, no explanation given.

> **CC:** Storm Shadow. Never a doubt.
> **SS:** Cobra Commander.
> **CC:** (Looks at restrained Destro) Destro. You're out of the band.

This seems confusing, considering how important *Destro* can be to CC's plan for eventual world domination, as *Destro* is a renowned arms dealer and a resourceful man. Not to forget that in the prequel, *CC* healed *Destro* after his face got disfigured after an attack. Why not free *Destro* from the prison?

Comment: Destroy WAS an arms dealer. It's unlikely he would have been allowed any remaining business interests after significant acts of terrorism.  Plus he's not important to the plot of this movie.

Comment: Oh and you also don't have to pay Christopher Eccleston's not inconsiderable fee.